# Moving/Dressing mesh in 3D engine (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, textures, mesh

I'm new in 3D games developing so I have kinda dummy question - how to move a mesh in 3D engine (under moving I mean a walking animation). And how to dress some skin on it?

What I have:

1. open source 3D OpenGL engine - NinevehGL http://nineveh.gl/. It's super easy to load a mesh
   to. I' pretty sure it will be awesome engine when it will be released!
2. a mesh model of the human.
       http://www.2shared.com/file/RTBEvSbf/female.html (it's mesh of a
       female that I downloaded from some open source web site..)
3. found a
       web site from which I can download skeleton animation in
   formats:
       dao (COLLADA) , XML , BVH (?) - http://www.animeeple.com/details/bcd6ac4b-ebc9-465e-9233-ed0220387fb9
4. what I stuck on (see attached image)

[image]

So, how can I join all these things and make simple game when dressed human will walk forward and backward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is difficult to answer, because it would require knowledge of the engine's API. Also you can't just stick a skeletal animation onto some mesh. You need some connection between both, a process called rigging, in which you add "bones" (also called armatures) to the mesh. This is an artistic process, done in a 3D modeller. Then you need to implement a skeletal animation system, which is a far too complex task to answer in a single Stackoverflow answer (it involves animation curve evaluation, quaternion interpolation, skinning matrices, etc.).

You should break down your question into smaller pieces.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. the mesh already has a skeleton. and I can move it's connection points in Blender. but how to do it in code? I do not expect the answer relative to Engine. But can you please send me few links describing such process, at least in theory. Thanks

Comment: @Dmitry: There's an entry in the OpenGL wiki, HTH: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation

Answer (score 2):

I'm a BETA Tester for Nineveh Engine.
Currently, the engine does not support bones/skeleton animation. This will be a part of their next release version which is upcoming in next 4-8 months.

Future (Roadmap)
Version 0.9.3 : Q4 2011 - Q1 2012
Bones, Rigging and Mesh's Animations.
Mesh Morph.

You might want to checkout http://nineveh.gl/docs/changelog/